# asp.net MVC 4 SSN Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I am looking for an attribute for SSN Validation.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Social Security is Required")]
[SSN]
public string SSN { get; set; }
```

I know this doesn't work, but this is what I am looking for.

Can anyone Help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a Regex.
Try something like this.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "SSN is Required")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Social Security Number")]
public string SSN { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Regex.

```
[RegularExpression(@"[1-9]{1}\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Social Security Number")]
```

This Regex also check's that the first digit must not be zero.

Comment: Yes, if a person is born in the Northeast. SSN's are not completely random. That's why SSN's are important to safeguard, especially the last four digits, which are the most identifying. https://www.lavasurfer.com/info/socialsecurity.html

Comment: I also found "Any number beginning with "000", "666", "900-999", has a middle "00", or ends in "0000" will never be a valid SSN." in your provided reference.

Then what would be the most accurate Regex for validating SSN?
@Calculuswhiz

Comment: Can you use more than one `RegularExpressionAttribute`? For example, use a negative lookahead, something like `(?!000|666|9).*`, to account for the first three digits. I would do that instead of trying to cram it all into one expression.